# Solve a partial differential equation in two variables by specifing value of the solution in a region

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

Is it possible, when using `DSolve` to solve a partial differential equation, to specify the value of the solution in a finite domain? 
For example, to find the function $\phi(x_1,x_2)$, (with $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$) that satisfies the equation

$-i(\partial_{x_1} + \partial_{x_2}) \phi(x_1,x_2) = A \phi(x_1,x_2) $,

with the condition that $\phi(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1,x_2)$ in the third quadrant, i.e. for $x_1,x_2<0$.

$f(x_1,x_2)$ is a known function and $A$ is just a parameter.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all but the third quadrant, `ϕ` satisfies

```
s = DSolveValue[-I (D[ϕ[x1, x2], x1] + D[ϕ[x1, x2], x2]) == 
        a ϕ[x1, x2], ϕ[x1, x2], {x1, x2}]
(* E^(I a x1) C[1][-x1 + x2] *)
```

where `C[1]` is an arbitrary function of `x2 - x1`.  Boundary conditions are applied at the edges of the third quadrant,

```
(s /. x1 -> 0) == f[0, x2] (* x2 < 0 *)
(* C[1][x2] == f[0, x2] *)

(s /. x2 -> 0) == f[x1, 0] (* x1 < 0 *)
(* E^(I a x1) C[1][-x1] == f[x1, 0] *)
```

It follows, therefore, that `C[1]` is given by

```
C[1][x2-x1] -> Piecewise[{{Exp[I a (x2 - x1)] f[x1 - x2, 0], x2 - x1 > 0}, 
    {f[0, x2 - x1], x2 - x1 < 0}}]
```

and `ϕ` is given by

```
Piecewise[{{E^(I*a*x2)*f[x1 - x2, 0], x1 < x2}, {E^(I*a*x1)*f[0, -x1 + x2], x1 > x2}}, 0]
```

The validity of this expression can be verified by inserting it into the PDE and the two boundary conditions given above.

To illustrate the solution, consider

```
f[x_, y_] := x + y
```

designate the solution given above by `ss`, substitute `a -> 1`, and set the solution to `f[x1, x2]` in the third quadrant.  Then,

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[ReIm[Piecewise[{{f[x1, x2], x1 < 0 && x2 < 0}}, ss /. a -> 1]]], 
    {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {x1, x2, ϕ}, Exclusions -> None, 
    PlotPoints -> 50, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Black, Medium], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

where the real part of the solution is in orange, and the imaginary part in blue.  Visibly the solution is continuous everywhere.  Its first derivative need not be continuous, however, because the PDE is only first-order.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's very clear and helpful!